# Is there a way to download wikipedia pages programmatically?

Tags: command-line, python, download

I'd like to download some Wikipedia pages as part of a program. Currently I would go to the pages on a browser, click "Download as PDF" manually, wait for it to render, then download it, then rename it and move it to the location I want. I'd like to automate this either by doing the downloading them in bash or Python. Is this possible (without using webdriver)?

Comment: Just two quick links to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/a/627606/935614 and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page. Or do you want them as PDF and not only the content?

Comment: Thanks. I just want to dump them as pdf as reference (for something that I might read later). I don't need to parse the content.